# Collapse sequences of numbers into ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Today I'm requesting help with a Python script that I'm writing; I'm using the CSV module to parse a large document with about 1,100 rows, and from each row it's pulling a Case_ID, a unique number that no other row has.  For example:

```
['10215', '10216', '10277', '10278', '10279', '10280', '10281', '10282', '10292', '10293',
'10295', '10296', '10297', '10298', '10299', '10300', '10301', '10302', '10303', '10304',
'10305', '10306', '10307', '10308', '10309', '10310', '10311', '10312', '10313', '10314',
'10315', '10316', '10317', '10318', '10319', '10320', '10321', '10322', '10323', '10324',
'10325', '10326', '10344', '10399', '10400', '10401', '10402', '10403', '10404', '10405',
'10406', '10415', '10416', '10417', '10418', '10430', '10448', '10492', '10493', '10494',
'10495', '10574', '10575', '10576', '10577', '10578', '10579', '10580', '10581', '10582',
'10583', '10584', '10585', '10586', '10587', '10588', '10589', '10590', '10591', '10592',
'10593', '10594', '10595', '10596', '10597', '10598', '10599', '10600', '10601', '10602',
'10603', '10604', '10605', '10606', '10607', '10608', '10609', '10610', '10611', '10612',
'10613', '10614', '10615', '10616', '10617', '10618', '10619', '10620', '10621', '10622',
'10623', '10624', '10625', '10626', '10627', '10628', '10629', '10630', '10631', '10632',
'10633', '10634', '10635', '10636', '10637', '10638', '10639', '10640', '10641', '10642',
'10643', '10644', '10645', '10646', '10647', '10648', '10649', '10650', '10651', '10652',
'10653', '10654', '10655', '10656', '10657', '10658', '10659', '10707', '10708', '10709',
'10710', '10792', '10793', '10794', '10795', '10908', '10936', '10937', '10938', '10939',
'11108', '11109', '11110', '11111', '11112', '11113', '11114', '11115', '11116', '11117',
'11118', '11119', '11120', '11121', '11122', '11123', '11124', '11125', '11126', '11127',
'11128', '11129', '11130', '11131', '11132', '11133', '11134', '11135', '11136', '11137',
'11138', '11139', '11140', '11141', '11142', '11143', '11144', '11145', '11146', '11147',
'11148', '11149', '11150', '11151', '11152', '11153', '11154', '11155', '11194', '11195',
'11196', '11197', '11198', '11199', '11200', '11201', '11202', '11203', '11204', '11205',
'11206', '11207', '11208', '11209', '11210', '11211', '11212', '11213', '11214', '11215',
'11216', '11217', '11218', '11219', '11220', '11221', '11222', '11223', '11224', '11225',
'11226', '11227', '11228', '11229', '11230', '11231', '11232', '11233', '11234', '11235',
'10101', '10102', '10800', '11236']
```

As you can see, this list is quite an eyeful, so I'd like to include a small little function in my script that can reduce all of the sequential ranges down to hyphenated bookends of a sort, for example 10,277 - 10,282.

Thanks to all for any help included! Have a great day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doable. Let's see if this can be done with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['10215', '10216', '10277', ...]
# Load data as series.
s = pd.Series(data)
# Find all consecutive rows with a difference of one 
# and bin them into groups using `cumsum`. 
v = s.astype(int).diff().bfill().ne(1).cumsum() 
# Use `groupby` and `apply` to condense the consecutive numbers into ranges.
# This is only done if the group size is >1.
ranges = (
    s.groupby(v).apply(
        lambda x: '-'.join(x.values[[0, -1]]) if len(x) > 1 else x.item()).tolist())
```

```
print (ranges)
['10215-10216',
 '10277-10282',
 '10292-10293',
 '10295-10326',
 '10344',
 '10399-10406',
 '10415-10418',
 '10430',
 '10448',
 '10492-10495',
 '10574-10659',
 '10707-10710',
 '10792-10795',
 '10908',
 '10936-10939',
 '11108-11155',
 '11194-11235',
 '10101-10102',
 '10800',
 '11236']
```

Your data must be sorted for this to work.

Comment: so maybe instead of `data = ['10215', '10216', '10277', ...]` start with `data = sorted(int(i) for i in ['10215', '10216', '10277', ...])`?

Comment: @Dilettant Could be. If that is the behaviour OP wants. I'm leaving that detail out so OP can either add the code to sort the data themselves, or let it fail if it isn't.

Comment: Ok, but then `sorted(['123', '99'])` might come as a surprise ... :-)

Comment: This worked flawlessly! I'll make it so that the data is sorted. Thank you so much for the help! :D

Comment: @LukeCollins Added some comments so you can understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Go pandas.! (-:

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a simple loop here with the following logic:

1. Create a list to store the ranges (`ranges`).
2. Iterate over the values in your list (`l`)
3. If `ranges` is empty, append a list with the first value in `l` to `ranges`
4. Otherwise if the difference between the current and previous value is 1, append the current value to the last list in `ranges`
5. Otherwise append a list with the current value to `ranges`

Code:

```
l = ['10215', '10216', '10277', '10278', '10279', '10280', ...]

ranges = []
for x in l:
    if not ranges:
        ranges.append([x])
    elif int(x)-prev_x == 1:
        ranges[-1].append(x)
    else:
        ranges.append([x])
    prev_x = int(x)
```

Now you can compute your final ranges by concatenating the first and last element of each list in `ranges` (if there are at least 2 elements).

```
final_ranges = ["-".join([r[0], r[-1]] if len(r) > 1 else r) for r in ranges]
print(final_ranges)
#['10215-10216',
# '10277-10282',
# '10292-10293',
# '10295-10326',
# '10344',
# '10399-10406',
# '10415-10418',
# '10430',
# '10448',
# '10492-10495',
# '10574-10659',
# '10707-10710',
# '10792-10795',
# '10908',
# '10936-10939',
# '11108-11155',
# '11194-11235',
# '10101-10102',
# '10800',
# '11236']
```

This also assumes your data is sorted. You could simplify the code to combine items 3 and 5.

---

For purely educational purposes (this is much more inefficient that the loop above), here's the same thing using `map` and `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

def myreducer(ranges, x):
    if not ranges:
        return [[x]]
    elif (int(x) - int(ranges[-1][-1]) == 1):
        return ranges[:-1] + [ranges[-1]+[x]] 
    else:
        return ranges + [[x]]

final_ranges = map(
    lambda r: "-".join([r[0], r[-1]] if len(r) > 1 else r),
    reduce(myreducer, l, [])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [pynumparser](https://pypi.org/project/pynumparser/) package:

```
import pynumparser         

pynumparser.NumberSequence().encode([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10])
# result: '1-3,5-8,10'

pynumparser.NumberSequence().parse('1-3,5-8,10')              
# result: (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10)
```