# How to consolidate a list of mixed integers (#-#, #-#, etc.)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to consolidate a sorted list of mixed integers into a list of strings in the format `#-#, #-#, #, #, #-#, etc.`

My current partially completes the job, but the while loop ends before it finishes consolidating the entire list. I cannot figure out why this is happening. In my code below I shorted my integer list as the one I am working with is too long to paste in here.

```
sorted_int_list = [1,2,3, 50,51, 66, 450,451,452, ...]

i = 0
current = None
anchor = None
first = True
consolidated = []

while i < len(sorted_int_list):
    if current is None:
        current = sorted_int_list[i]
        if first:
            anchor = current
        else:
            anchor = current - 1
    elif sorted_int_list[i] == current + 1:
        current = sorted_int_list[i]
    else:
        consolidated.append(str(anchor - 1) + '-' + str(sorted_int_list[i-1]))
        current = None
        first = False
    i += 1
```

The desired output is a complete list in the following format:

`1-3, 50-51, 66, 450-452, ...`

**You can see my actual input/output here: https://pastebin.com/NTFzk7Dd**

As you can see it stops at 13663-13881 but the input list goes to 15178

Comment: can you provide an example of your input/output?

Comment: You can see my actual input/output here: https://pastebin.com/NTFzk7Dd

Comment: what happens with the 2 of your input? I mean with the second element of your input list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapse sequences of numbers into ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302243/collapse-sequences-of-numbers-into-ranges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In Python you can iterate through a list *without* using the index of the element.
- The following code *assumes* that the list is non-empty. It can be modified to handle that case as well.

```
sorted_int_list=[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11]
start=sorted_int_list[0]
end=start
output=[]
for a in sorted_int_list[1:]:
    if a==end+1:
        end=a
    else:
        output.append((start,end))
        start=a
        end=a
output.append((start,end))
consolidated=[str(s)+'-'+str(e) for (s,e) in output]
```

This gives the value of `consolidated` as:

```
['1-3', '5-8', '10-11']
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute the algorithm using pen and paper. Here was your algorithm
before your edits:

```
sorted_int_list = [1,2,3, 50,51, 66, 450,451,452]
i = 0
current = None
anchor = None
consolidated = []
while i < len(sorted_int_list):
    if current is None:
        current = sorted_int_list[i]
        anchor = current
    elif sorted_int_list[i] == current + 1:
        current = sorted_int_list[i]
    else:
        consolidated.append(str(anchor - 1) + '-' + str(sorted_int_list[i-1]))
        current = None
        anchor = None
    i += 1
```

First you have these five lines which sets variables

```
sorted_int_list = [1,2,3, 50,51, 66, 450,451,452]
i = 0
current = None
anchor = None
consolidated = []
```

Then

```
while i < len(sorted_int_list):
```

Since i is less than `len(sorted_int_list) = 9`, we enter the
loop. Then

```
if current is None:
```

Since `current = None`, we enter the if:

```
current = sorted_int_list[i]
anchor = current
```

After these two statements, our variables have these values:

```
sorted_int_list = [1,2,3, 50,51, 66, 450,451,452]
i = 0
current = sorted_int_list[i] = 1
anchor = 1
```

Then we exit the if-block and execute:

```
i += 1
```

So now `i = 1`. i is still less than 9 so we rerun the loop. But now
`current = 1` so `if current is None:` doesn't trigger. Instead:

```
elif sorted_int_list[i] == current + 1:
```

will trigger because `sorted_int_list[i] = 2` is equal to `current +
1´. So we enter the block:

```
current = sorted_int_list[i]
```

After execution, `current` is therefore equal to 2. Then

```
i += 1
```

So now `i = 2`. We again run the loop to completion and if you do it
on paper, you'll see that the variables becomes:

```
anchor = 1
current = 3
i = 3
```

Then we do it again and now comes the interesting part:

```
if current is None:
```

Won't trigger because `current = 3`.

```
elif sorted_int_list[i] == current + 1:
```

Won't trigger either because `sorted_int_list[i] = sorted_int_list[3]
= 50` but `current + 1 = 4`. Clearly `50 != 4` therefore we enter the
`else:`. The first statement in it is:

```
consolidated.append(str(anchor - 1) + '-' + str(sorted_int_list[i-1]))
```

Again, running this in your head, you an simplify it like this:

```
consolidated.append(str(anchor - 1) + '-' + str(sorted_int_list[i-1]))
consolidated.append(str(1 - 1) + '-' + str(sorted_int_list[3-1]))
consolidated.append('0' + '-' + str(sorted_int_list[2]))
consolidated.append('0' + '-' + str(3))
consolidated.append('0' + '-' + '3')
consolidated.append('0-3')
```

Here is your first bug. It should append `1-3` not `0-3`, right? Can
you spot the error? Continuing executing:

```
current = None
anchor = None
```

This is fine, those variables are now resetted. And then:

```
i += 1
```

Also fine. All variables are now

```
current = None
anchor = None
i = 4
consolidated = ['0-3']
sorted_int_list = [1,2,3, 50,51, 66, 450,451,452]
```

Loop runs again, and since `current = None`, we execute:

```
current = sorted_int_list[i] = sorted_int_list[4] = 51
anchor = current = 51
```

To save some vertical space im using multiple equal signs to denote
what the variables values becomes. Here perhaps you see that something
is fishy? Why didn't the loop pick up 50? Continuing

```
i += 1 = 5
```

and we loop again. Now

```
sorted_int_list[i] = sorted_int_list[5] = 66
current + 1 = 51 + 1 = 52
```

52 != 66 so we enter the `else:` of the loop:

```
consolidated.append(str(anchor - 1) + '-' + str(sorted_int_list[i-1]))
consolidated.append(str(51 - 1) + '-' + str(sorted_int_list[5-1]))
consolidated.append(str(50) + '-' + str(sorted_int_list[4]))
consolidated.append(str(50) + '-' + str(51))
consolidated.append('50-51')
```

This looks right, but is it really? What would have happened if the
list started with `[1,2,3,40,51,...` rather than `[1,2,3,50,51,...`?
Continuing

```
i += 1 = 6
```

and we loop again. Now `current = None` so the first branch of the if
is taken:

```
current = sorted_int_list[i] = sorted_int_list[6] = 450
anchor = current = 450
```

This is not great. Why hasn't the algorithm picked up the value 66? It
seems like your code "forgets" some numbers. How come?

Hint: Add something to the `else:` clause of the if-statement and also
add something that is run after the while-loop is done. There might be
an extra item to add to the `consolidated` list.